# Use is_product_category() properly

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, archives

I have two product category

1. MULTILINGUAL DIGITAL MARKETING (ID 75)
2. INTERNATIONAL SALES CHANNELS (ID 107)

I want to  run some code via if condition for these two category only.

I tried using this code but it didn't worked

```
if( is_product_category(107 || 75) ) { 

$term = get_queried_object();

$parent = $term->parent;

if (!empty($parent)) {
    $child_of = $parent;
} else {
    $child_of = $term->term_id;
}

$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
    'child_of'      => $child_of,
) );

if ($terms) {
    foreach ( $terms as $category ) {

        $category_id = $category->term_id;
        $category_slug = $category->slug;
        $category_name = $category->name;
        $category_desc = $category->description;

        echo '<div class="'.$category_slug.'">';

        echo '<h2>'.$category_name.'</h2>';

        if ($category_desc) {
            echo '<p>'.$category_desc.'</p>';
        }

        $products_args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'product', 
            'tax_query'     => array( 
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => $category_id, 
                ),
            ),
        );

        $products = new WP_Query( $products_args );

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) { // only start if we hace some products

            // START some normal woocommerce loop

            woocommerce_product_loop_start();

            if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {

                while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();

                    /**
                     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                     *
                     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

                endwhile; // end of the loop.

            }

            woocommerce_product_loop_end();

            // END the normal woocommerce loop

            // Restore original post data, maybe not needed here (in a plugin it might be necessary)
            wp_reset_postdata();

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is_product_category()` is to be used on woocommerce category archive pages only so first make sure that you are on category archive.

instead of category number use category slug name `is_product_category('category-slug')`

no need to run  OR(||) condition just use `is_product_category('category-slug1','category-slug2')` to get same output

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if( is_product_category( 'category1-slug' ) || is_product_category( 'category2-slug' ) ) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a few categories, you should use slugs in array when you use is_product_category() function. Below example. Tested and works.

```
if( is_product_category( array('category1-slug', 'category2-slug' )) )
```